# Connecting to external data in Wave Analytics

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics

I gather that with Wave Analytics we can import data from external sources (data that lives outside Salesforce, e.g. SQL Server). Just wondering when we import the data into Wave as datasets is there any additional cost associated with storing that data in salesforce?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, there isn't any additional cost when you are importing data from external sources. I don't think u can import from SQl server. Below are the sources I see(at least in my org).
[image: Data Import Sources]
Note that it is a painful time taking process to import data into salesforce. Also, the data needs to be cleansed at source level before uploading as you don't many options in Wave (right now).
Also if you are importing data from csv file, there is a limit of 500Mb.

Answer (score 1):

Wave Analytics has a row storage limit of 250 million per platform license purchased before October 20, 2015.

Full details can be found here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=bi_limits.htm

So to answer the question, storage is included provided you stay within your limits.

Answer (score 0):

Your organization will have a limit on data storage amount according to the license type that you have.  I am not sure whether this impacts your wave analytics data storage amount or not.  You should speak with salesforce about your specific organization to make sure.

Source: System overview within salesforce org

The .csv file upload can actually be completed on data sets up to 40 GB.  The catch is that anything over 500 MB has to be uploaded using the "External Data API".  You can find a full walk through on this at:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/bi_ext_data_connect_to_sf.htm